# Relationship between direction of magnetic force and movement of a ring

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose a metallic ring is dropped from above a magnet (N is pointing up and S is pointing down). Why does the "direction" of the magnetic force on the ring stay the same when it enters the ring and when it leave the ring?

Is it because the magnetic field produced by the magnet is constant?

But if you think about the relative position of the ring when it enters the magnet and when it leaves the magnet...

(i) when it enters the magnet which has N pointing up, I can intuitively understand that the magnetic force that the ring feels is pointed upward as magnetic flux project upwards from the N end.

My confusion arises when the ring is leaving the magnet.

(ii) when it is leaving the magnet, isn't the magnetic flux coming out of the S end of the magnet directed downward (that is, the direction of the force on the ring is downward as well?

I am baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Lenz’s law as trying to reduce the change inducing the emf which in turn is producing an induced current.

At first when travelling down the ring is moving into a region of higher magnetic field and so the flux passing through it is increasing.
The induced currents interacting with the magnetic field produces a force trying to push the ring back into a region of lower magnetic field ie upwards.
Of course the induced current never wins but it does produce an upward force which slows the downward passage of the ring.

Once the ring passes region of maximum magnetic field near the north pole of the magnet the magnetic field starts to decrease and the force due to the induced current tries to push the ring into a region of higher magnetic field ie the force is upwards.

Carrying on and with the ring nearing the south pole of the magnet the magnetic field is increasing and so again the force due to the induced current is upwards in the direction of decreasing magnetic field.

Passing the south pole the magnetic field due the magnet is decreasing and so yet again the force due to the induced current is upwards in the direction of increasing magnetic field.

Just think of the magnetic flux changing and he force due to the induced current trying to reduce that change.